# Triple integral - finding mass of solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find the mass of the solid (constant density $\rho $) which is bounded by the surface $x=y^2$ and the planes $x=z, z=0, x=1.$. Now I'm having a hard time visualising/sketching it as you would for just a double integral.

I tried some stuff and came up with $y^2\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq x $ and so I got the mass as being given by the iterated integrals $$\int_{-1}^1dy\int_{y^2}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{x}\rho \ dz$$ but I'm not too sure about this.

[same as $$\int_{-1}^1\int_{y^2}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\rho \ dzdxdy$$]

Comment: One of planes need correction $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote it twice for some reason.

Comment: You keep writing your integrals in the wrong way. You cannot write $\int_{-1}^1 dy \int_{y^2}^1 dx$. Instead, write $\int_{-1}^1  \int_{y^2}^1 dx\;dy$

Comment: It's just different notation that I see being used. Is what I put correct though?

Comment: Why $-1\leq y\leq1$ and isn't $0\leq y\leq1$.? The solid is symmetric.?

Comment: I thought the fact that $y^2\leq x $ and $x\leq 1 $ meant that $-1\leq y\leq 1 $ - as I said I'm really not sure because I'm having trouble of visualising the solid bound by the surfaces.